# codeigniter change third party application language

Tags: php, codeigniter

My thirdparty app comes with languages support in it. 
Do I have to 'manually' copy the language folder to 'application/language' ? 
Is so, what the use of `$autoload['language'] = array('thirdparty');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the package path to the codeigniter loader:

```
$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/foo_bar/');
```

After you will be able to load it's language file normally:

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

Take a look at: [CodeIgniter Loader Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html)